# HTML: Displaying all contents of a folder with a certain file extension? Mainly Images.

Tags: image

Alright...so I am an amateur web designer looking for cleaner ways to display new images, or content. One of my current goals is to find a way to display the images in a folder, into a gallery type situation. This way all I have to do is upload the image into the folder, hit refresh, and there it is. I do not want to have to use coding to have to put in the new image everytime I upload one.

Does anyone know of a way to do this "from scratch" So to speak? (Languages, etc.) If at all possible, I want to avoid pre-made ones that are available with Joomla, Wordpress, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give a bit more explanation of what you actually want to do and what you've tried?